# NullPointerException while formatting date using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, simpledateformat

This is the code that is getting the null pointer exception:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
String temp = df.format(load.getDeliveryDate());
System.out.println(temp);
date.setText(temp);
```

This is my code that creates a random date (for test data):

```
private Date randomDate(){
    int month, year, day;  
    Random call = new Random();  
    month = call.nextInt(12); 
    year = call.nextInt(2012);
    day  = call.nextInt(31);
    Date toReturn = new Date(year, month, day);
    System.out.println(toReturn.toString());
    return toReturn;
}
```

I was originally getting an error on the line that is setting the text for my date item.  Now I'm also getting an error on my date format declaration line.

I'm already checking load to make sure it is not null.  It is a custom class that includes a Date attribute.

Logcat Output (after rebuild):

```
04-30 12:56:10.423: E/AndroidRuntime(8212): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 12:56:10.423: E/AndroidRuntime(8212): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 12:56:10.423: E/AndroidRuntime(8212):     at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1325)
04-30 12:56:10.423: E/AndroidRuntime(8212):     at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.formatImpl(SimpleDateFormat.java:536)
04-30 12:56:10.423: E/AndroidRuntime(8212):     at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:818)
04-30 12:56:10.423: E/AndroidRuntime(8212):     at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:376)
```

Comment: What's the value of `load` from `load.getDeliveryDate()`?  Is it null?  And if so, why are you calling a function from a null class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the stack trace you've posted the date format is not null, but the date (probably) is.

```
04-30 12:56:10.423: E/AndroidRuntime(8212):     at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:376)
```

This line of the stack trace tells us this was a problem with formatting the date. But it also tells us that there the format object exists.  We know the object was initialized with a string (not a null pointer) and internal bugs in such libraries are *very rare*.

So there may be something wrong with the `load.getDeliveryDate()` call returning a `null` date.  You have not posted this yet, so I can't really comment.

You describe in your question that:

> I was originally getting an error on the line that is setting the text
>   for my date item. Now I'm also getting an error on my date format
>   declaration line.

Since this clearly can not be null, it appears there is a mismatch between the code running on your device and the code you have running in your IDE (Eclipse?).

This can happen from time to time. For some reason the application does not get updated with the new version of some or all of your classes.  When you get any evidence this has happened (*which you appear to*) the best thing is to completely uninstall the app and do a full project clean.  When you attempt to run the app after that it will push a full clean copy onto the device which should make debugging much easier.

Comment: For some reason load.getDeliveryDate() is returning null.  I put in a check and am recalling randomDate() which is working.

Answer (score -1):

new Date(int year, int month, int day) is deprecated. You can use Gregorian calendar instead

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
    String temp = df.format(randomDate());
    System.out.println(temp);
}

private static Date randomDate(){
    int month, year, day;  
    Random call = new Random();  
    month = call.nextInt(11); // month -> 0 to 11 for gregorian calendar
    year = call.nextInt(2012);
    day  = call.nextInt(31);
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    Date toReturn = cal.getTime();
    System.out.println(toReturn.toString());
    return toReturn;
}
```

If you get a NullPointerException, the field must be null. Just use

```
 if(date != null)
       date.setText(temp);
```